# OpenGL issue with QT5 qml applications on I.MX53-based board

Tags: opengl, embedded, qml, qt5, yocto

I have *DIGI ConnectCore* development kit, based on *I.MX53* microprocessor, on which iI'm trying to launch *QT5 QML*-based application. But building rootfs image  by means of *Yocto* doesn't bring good results.

I use *Ubuntu (64-bit version 14.04)* virtual machine and following meta-layers (both "daisy" and "dizzy" branches I've tried):

1. Those from *Freescale community* ([Github](https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform));
2. *Meta-qt5 layer* ([Github](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5))
   I have already tried `fsl-image-multimedia(-full)` recipe with modified **local.conf**, which contents concering *QT5* I get from [this link](http://wiki.wandboard.org/index.php/Building_Qt5_using_yocto_on_Wandboard).

I have to say, builds was successful, but I haven't managed to launch *QT Quick*-based applications (those one based on widgets runs well), and I've got following errors from debug console, when I run app under *X-window* system (by using `"-platform xcb" postfix`):

> Could not find of the system's Compose files. Consider setting the QTCOMPOSE environment setting.
>   QxbIntegration: cannot create platform opengl context, neither GLX nor EGL enabled
>   Failed to create openGL context for format qsurfaceformat

... and such errors I've got when run with *eglfs plugin* (`-platform eglfs`):

> Could not find of the system's Compose files. Consider setting the QTCOMPOSE environment setting.
>   Could not create the egl surface: error = 0x300b.

I realize that such messages points to *OpenGL*-related problems, but I cannot understand, what's the reason. *GPU*-related packages are included in build (I mean "**amd-gpu-bin-mx51**" and "**imx-vpu**"). I have tried both *X* and direct framebuffer (by adding `DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11 wayland"` in **local.conf**) variants, but with no success.

Do I need to get some special packages on configs in order to get *QML* applications working?